# Crossing elements from two different lists

Tags: r, list

I have two lists like this:

```
> output
[[1]]
   A   C freq
1 11 432    2
4 51 332    3

[[2]]
   A B   C freq
5 51 5 332    3

> k
[[1]]
[1] "A,C,freq"

[[2]]
[1] "A,B,C,freq"
```

The second one are the names from the first one.

I would like to get this output (a character vector ordered by freq):

```
> output2
[1] "A == 51 & B == 5 & C == 332 & freq == 3"
[2] "A == 51 & C == 332 & freq == 3"    
[3] "A == 11 & C == 432 & freq == 2"
```

And I have tried the following:

```
> for (j in 1:length(output)){
+   t[[j]]=as.character(paste("output[[j]]",noquote(k[[j]]),sep=","))
+   
+ }

> t
[1] "output[[j]],A,C,freq"
[2] "output[[j]],A,B,C,freq"

> tests <- function(data, ...){
+   colN <- c(...)
+   tmp <- get(data, envir = parent.frame())[colN]
+   Reduce(function(...) paste(..., sep=" & "),
+          Map(paste, names(tmp), tmp, MoreArgs = list(sep=" == ")))
+   
+ }

> output2=list()
> for (j in 1:length(t)){
+   output2[[j]] <- lapply(strsplit(t, ","), function(x) tests(x[1], 
+   x[-1]))}
```

And I get an error, because the last loop does not recognize the strings in the t vector.
If I try this:

```
ll=output[[1]]
output3 <- c(sapply(strsplit("ll,A,C,freq", ","), function(x) tests(x[1], 
+ x[-1])))
> output3
[1] "A == 11 & C == 432 & freq == 2" 
[2] "A == 51 & C == 332 & freq == 3"
```

it works well (although it is not ordered by freq), but I can have big lists, that is why I have done a loop.

I would appreciate if someone could help me with this issue.

Comment: Why do you want to produce those strings? Are you planning to use `eval(parse(...))` on them later?

Comment: I have tried it with similar loops, but it was slow and complicated with big lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be missing something. how does `k` come into the picture?

If I understand correctly, you can create your "Text" column first, rbind all together then order by `freq` in descending order as follows:

```
outls <- lapply(output, function(x) {
    x$Text <- Reduce(function(...) paste(..., sep=" & "),
        Map(paste, names(x), x, MoreArgs = list(sep=" == ")))  
    x
})

out <- plyr::rbind.fill(outls)
out[order(-out$freq), "Text"]
```

data:

```
output <- list(
    data.frame(A=c(11, 51), C=c(432, 332), freq=c(2,3)),
    data.frame(A=51, B=5, C=332, freq=3))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is what I wanted, it works very well.